# Mysql error in order by desc

Tags: mysql

this is my query.when i add order by desc in this query its gets an error pls help me.

```
SELECT *
FROM
  (SELECT package_details.*,
          r.state AS source_name,
          d.state AS dest_name
   FROM (`package_details`)
   LEFT JOIN country_state_city r ON r.id=package_details.region_id
   LEFT JOIN country_state_city d ON d.id=package_details.destination_id
   WHERE `package_availability_type` = 'all'
     AND `admin_status` = 'ACTIVE'
     AND `status` = 'ACTIVE'
     AND (package_name LIKE '%Istanbul%'
          OR routes LIKE '%Istanbul%'
          OR r.state LIKE '%Istanbul%'
          OR d.state LIKE '%Istanbul%')
     AND
   ORDER BY `package_price` DESC
   UNION ALL SELECT package_details.*,
                    r.state AS source_name,
                    d.state AS dest_name
   FROM (`package_details`)
   LEFT JOIN country_state_city r ON r.id=package_details.region_id
   LEFT JOIN country_state_city d ON d.id=package_details.destination_id
   WHERE `package_availability_type` ='range'
     AND `admin_status` = 'ACTIVE'
     AND `status` = 'ACTIVE'
     AND `to_date` >= '2017-02-07'
     AND (package_name LIKE '%Istanbul%'
          OR routes LIKE '%Istanbul%'
          OR r.state LIKE '%Istanbul%'
          OR d.state LIKE '%Istanbul%')
     AND
   ORDER BY `package_price` DESC) AS dt LIMIT 0,100
```

error:
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ORDER BY `package_price` DESC UNION ALL SELECT package_details.*,r.state AS sour' at line 1

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Remove `AND` Before Order By Clause

```
 AND
   ORDER BY `package_price` DESC
```